# Plotly figures in Jupyterlab with no horizontal scroll bar

Tags: python, scroll, plotly, jupyter-lab

If the plotly Figure is wider than the screen, I cannot see the right part because the horizontal scroll bar is not present.
I have something like this:
[image]

I looked for everywhere but it seems that no one had this problem before.
Any advices?
Thank you in advance

I also put the code here, as requested

```
import plotly.express as px

long_df = px.data.medals_long()

fig = px.bar(long_df, x="nation", y="count", color="medal", title="Long-Form Input")
fig.update_layout(width=1800, height=800)
```

Comment: Do not use images of code, instead copy and paste your code in the question as text and format it using cmd+k or ctrl+k

Comment: try cell --> All Output  ---> toggle scrolling

Comment: 'cell' exists in Jupyer Notebook but I cannot find the same in Jupyter Lab

Comment: @PaoloZ. not reproducible for me in jupyter lab

Comment: @It_is_Chris sorry I made a mistake. I updated the code

Comment: Same problem here, also cannot find a solution. Enabling scrolling cells only turns on vertical scrolling.